# Why did the Betan Hermaphrodite experiment fail?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

All we seem to be told in the Vorkosigan books is that the Hermaphrodites were a failed experiment a century ago. Is there any info beyond that on why exactly the experiment failed, how it failed? My assumption was always that it was an experiment in creating an entirely sexually equal society, which seems right up the Betans' alley, so what happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Courtesy of the author herself](http://bar.baen.com/index.php?t=msg&th=121390) (board membership needed to view post):

> The experiment "failed" not because herms weren't perfectly fine, viable people, but because they ended up merely being added to, instead of replacing, the prior model of human.  Thus, instead of erasing a two-way status argument, it augmented it to a three-way status argument, doing nothing to ease social noise and friction.
>
> ....
>
> Ta, L.

[image: Screenshot]